# java how get last date (or max date) from mongodb collection where userName=currentUserName

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a collection of logins with the following format:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("541d9aee784269c2e9f3c092"), "userName" : "dani", 
"loginDate" : ISODate("2020-01-22T21:08:28.994Z")},
{ "_id" : ObjectId("541d9aee7842sdfsdfsdddsf"), "userName" : "bar", 
"loginDate" : ISODate("2020-01-20T21:02:33.994Z")},
{ "_id" : ObjectId("541d9aee784dfgsdfgdfgdfg"), "userName" : "yacuv", 
"loginDate" : ISODate("2020-01-17T21:01:11.994Z")},
{ "_id" : ObjectId("541d9aee784dfgdfgdfgdfgd"), "userName" : "ran", 
"loginDate" : ISODate("2020-01-15T21:02:33.994Z")},
{ "_id" : ObjectId("541d9aee784269cvvchgfghh"), "userName" : "bar", 
"loginDate" : ISODate("2020-01-12T21:02:54.994Z")}}
```

How do I get the last entry date per user?

Comment: Please put your code in a code block.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the collection is called "yoval":

```
db.yoval.aggregate([{$group: {"_id" : "$userName", maxDate: {$max: "$loginDate"}}}])
```

produces:

```
{ "_id" : "yacuv", "maxDate" : ISODate("2020-01-17T21:01:11.994Z") }
{ "_id" : "ran", "maxDate" : ISODate("2020-01-15T21:02:33.994Z") }
{ "_id" : "bar", "maxDate" : ISODate("2020-01-20T21:02:33.994Z") }
{ "_id" : "dani", "maxDate" : ISODate("2020-01-22T21:08:28.994Z") }
```